# htaccess change default language without changing url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

An multilanguage wordpress site has multiple prefixes for languages (si,en,de,...)

```
1. https://www.example.com
2. https://www.example.com/porfolio/images
3. https://www.example.com/en
4. https://www.example.com/en/porfolio/images
```

Is there an .htaccess script, that would rewrite links 1,2 to 3,4 without changing the url?

My current script returns too many redirects, because of an apparent loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```